# problemas con query selector

Tags: javascript, html5

Si alguien me pudiera guiar en esto tengo este codigo js en donde pongo un queryselector:

```
document.querySelector("#content > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > table > tfoot > 
tr > td:nth-child(2)").outerHTML = '$10,000.00'
```

la ruta del query la estoy sacando con inspeccionar elemento de crome

la intencion es que ese numero que le estoy dando al query se traiga un dato de la base de datos, pero ahorita estoy haciendo la prueva para acomodar el html. la cuestion es que el html me lo muestra asi:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="4"></td>
    $10,000.00
                
</tr>
```

me lo pone fuera de un td y por lo tanto no se aplica el style de css. no encuentro la forma de solucionarlo. hace tiempo ya me había pasado y logre solucionarlos, pero en esta ocasión estoy batallando para encontrarle solución, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: cambia `.outerHTML` por  `.innerHTML` prueba y me dices ...

Comment: Porque reemplazas el elemento? no se supone que lo que quieres es agregar ese texto dentro del `td`? Como dice Arcanis, usa `innerHTML`

Comment: sii. funciona gracias. pero tengo la duda... en otra instruccion tengo lo mismo pero aplicado a una tabla y uso outerHTML, por que en este caso no funciona igual si estoy tratando de meter datos al HTML???

Comment: no probé tu codigo, pero a simple vista creo que debes añadir innerHTML en vez de .outerHTML, suerte!